booted into emergency shell "Can't find /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root"
Arch Linux:
I have two internal ssds in my laptop and I use one as my regular drive (lvm) and the other as a system backup drive. It does not happen every time, only sometimes but I'll get booted into the emergency shell because the system can't find my root partition on boot (lv_root in nvme0n1p3) but after I do a hard shutdown and Reboot, it finds the drive and everything it fine.
On my regular drive I have 3 partitions (nvme0n1p1 nvme0n1p2 nvme0n1p3) the third is where my root and home is and the second is the boot and first is the EFI.
My backup drive is nvme1n1 and it has no partitions but I noticed in the emergency shell that if I ls the /dev/ directory, I can see my drives listed as nvme0n1 , then nvme1n1p1 nvm1n1p2 nvm1n1p3, showing that the backup drive has the partitions and my regular drive does not.
So it seems like at boot the system is confusing my regular drive with my backup.
My question is why is my root partition unable to be found at boot even though the UUID is correct and could it be caused by also mounting my backup drive at boot?
Would appreciate any help if someone knows what might be causing this confusion between my ssds
Have tried:
Setting priority to 0 in etc/fstab for backup drive.
Updating the grub file.
Adding a 10 second wait time for the drive in grub.
Checking UUIDs.
Removing boot directory from being backed up.
UPDATE: After editing the grub config file with the suggested "cryptdevice=UUID=luksuuid:luksname" and also specifying the root in the line below, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="root=/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root", seems to have fixed the problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

nvme0 nvme1 can switch places same way sda sdb can - should not be an issue as long as you use UUIDs, which should be the default with lvm. any more specific error messages? boot parameters?

"the UUIDs are correct" where are they correct? How do you backup to the backup drive with no partitions?

@frostschutz other than the the system waiting to find the root partition and then dropping me into emergency shell when it can't and saying that its unable to find /dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_root , there are no other error messages. This is from my /default/grub : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 cryptdevice=/dev/nvme0n1p3:volgroup0 rootdelay=10 rd.lvm.wait=10" not sure if maybe it could be how i specify the cryptdevice how it doesn't say "mapper". I use UUIDs in fstab and have checked them with blkid so I know that is not causing the issue.

@JaromandaX They are correct in my fstab. I have a mount point at /mnt/backup and have put this in the fstab. `UUID=dc242f3d-5ca4-4b08-b4e9-5910a3de53bd /          ext4       rw,relatime 0 1
/dev/nvme0n1p2
UUID=a29c9b47-6178-4412-af67-1c90c21a6517 /boot      ext4       rw,relatime 0 2
/dev/mapper/volgroup0-lv_home
UUID=c58cad38-1ea7-4c47-a393-dfd32405bca6 /home      ext4       rw,relatime 0 2
/dev/nvme1n1
UUID=1d6127f5-9895-41c6-a467-bdae623b4bbd /mnt/backup ext4  rw,relatime 0 0`  I could try to change these all to "defaults" or add "lazytime" to the backup, not sure.

try cryptdevice=UUID=luksuuid:luksname with your luksuuid and desired luksname

@frostschutz thanks, trying this now. Booted up okay since updating grub  but it is usually random when it is unable to find and mount root so time will tell.
